# Why are only BUFFER_SIZE-1 items allowed in buffer in Producer-Consumer paradigm using shared memory?

Tags: c, operating-system, producer-consumer, circular-buffer

Here is an excerpt from the book "Operating System Concepts" 7th Edition Galvin,Gagne Chapter 3 from the hard-copy itself :

---

The following variables reside in a region of memory shared by the producer and consumer processes:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 10

typedef struct {
 . . .
} item;

item buffer[ BUFFER_SIZE ];
int in = 0;
int out = 0;
```

The shared buffer is implemented as a circular array with two logical pointers: **in** and **out**.The variable **in** points to the next free position in the buffer;**out** points to the first full position in the buffer.The buffer is empty when `in==out;` the buffer is full when `((in+1)%BUFFER_SIZE)==out`.

**This scheme allows at most `BUFFER_SIZE-1` items in the buffer at the same time.**

---

I have highlighted my confusion in **bold**.Here's a link to an online slide of that chapter (but it has edited a few lines of the book).Go to the section *"Producer-Consumer Example Using Shared Memory"*

http://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/OperatingSystems/3_Processes.html

Why can there be `BUFFER_SIZE-1` items in the buffer? If we start from `buffer[0]` to `buffer[BUFFERSIZE-1]`, doesn't it equal `BUFFER_SIZE` number of items? Does the author mean to say that the index of the buffer can't exceed `BUFFER_SIZE-1`?But then, he has clearly written the number of **items** can't exceed `BUFFER_SIZE-1` at the same time. Please explain the whole thing.

Comment: It is to facilitate his algorithm that when the head and tail of the circular buffer are residing on the same node (regardless of which node it is) the buffer is "empty". Therefore there will always be one node that cannot hold data. I've seen this before in other implementations, though this one is a bit baroque.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you have ring buffer, you typically have 2 pointers or offsets, which signify `start` and `end` of the data in the buffer. Typical convention to tell if buffer is empty when `start` == `end`.

This convention leads to `BUFFER_SIZE - 1` limitation on total numbers of items in ring buffer. If we were to allow to fill it to `BUFFER_SIZE`, this would mean that `start` == `end`, and thus would be impossible to tell if buffer is completely empty or completely full.

If you create one more variable that keeps number of items in the buffer, this would be possible to tell apart and allow to fill buffer to the max. But it is easier to not do that and simply reduce max number of items by 1.

Comment: @mvp Why can't we use `(in+2)%(BUFFER_SIZE+1)==out`?That way we can full the buffer to the max and still tell when it is full?

Comment: @WhozCraig Check out if you have anything to say about my comment above.

Comment: If `in` and `out` are ringbuffer offsets, they both must be from `0` to `BUFFER_SIZE-1`. With that, `(in-out)%BUFFER_SIZE` is number of elements currently in rungbuffer (`0` if `in==out`). But, if number of elements is `BUFFER_SIZE`, `(in-out)%BUFFER_SIZE` is also `0`. Your expression does not hold true if `in==out` (or when buffer is empty).

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture I've started typing up a response several times, but in the end mvp's answer is honestly the best explanation. `in == out` *must* signify exclusively one of the two possible conditions of "full" or "empty". If the latter, it means there must be a blank element at all times. If the former, you *must* account for "empty" some other way (an additional member that is a counter is the usual mechanism). Drawing it on paper *really* helps.

Comment: @mvp Thanks for following up your answer.It helped.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks to you too,you've always been nice and helpful.

Comment: @mvp how would I code the version with a maximum limit of BUFFER_SIZE? I don't understand the need of an extra variable.

Comment: @mozart: without extra variable it is impossible to tell if `in==out` means that buffer is completely empty or if buffer is completely full. So, this variable is needed for single purpose to tell this condition apart. However, it is much easier to simply increase BUFFER_SIZE by 1 and not use such variable in first place.

Comment: Sometimes access to a ring buffer is controlled by a pair of semaphores. In that case, it is not necessary to check whether the buffer is full, or check whether it is empty, and the buffer may contain BUFFER_SIZE items. The counters in the semaphores provide extra information so that **in**==**out** is not needed to signify exclusively one of the two possible conditions of "full" or "empty".